# How to take a div that is off screen and translate it to the middle of the screen using translateX()

Tags: jquery, html, css

Let me explain a little more in depth. I'm looking to have a div off screen. When a user clicks on a button I want the div to transition onto the screen.

```
<a href="#" id="button">Click Me</a>
   <div style="position:absolute;left:-100%;width:80%;height:80%;background:yellow; id="block" class="objecttransition"></div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
 $("#block".addClass("move");
}):
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.move
  {
    transform: translateX($$);
    -webkit-transform: translateX($$); /** Safari & Chrome **/
    -o-transform: translateX($$); /** Opera **/
    -moz-transform: translateX($$); /** Firefox **/
  }

.objecttransition
  {
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear; /** Chrome & Safari **/
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear; /** Firefox **/
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear; /** Opera **/
  }
```

My question now is by how much do I move the block to the right to make sure that the block is always in the middle of the screen regardless of the screen size??

Comment: why don't u `display:none` it and simply show it when it's needed?

Comment: why don't you use toggle ? or animate ?

Comment: Reason being is these animations I want to use in a phonegap application. I've used animate before problem is it runs horribly, much the same with toggle. But when I use straight up css it works very well as a phonegap application

Comment: @dan: changing display won't let you using CSS transform / transitions...

Comment: But you will have always the same `width` and `height` ? [Like This!](http://jsfiddle.net/M7nNw/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually can be done without any Javascript, anyway here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/lrsbck/2GEnD/) using jQuery.

```
<div>Hello!</div>
```

```
div {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 100%;
    width: 5rem;
    line-height: 5rem;
    text-align: center;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50 -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transition: 1200ms;
    -moz-transition: 1200ms;
    transition: 1200ms; }

div.foo {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```
$( document ).on('click', function() {
    $( 'div' ).toggleClass( 'foo' );
});
```

Comment: Thank you for such a legit answer!!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you're trying to move it into the screen using `translateX()` when you can just modify the `left` property to do it:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="button">Click Me</a>
<div id="block" class="objecttransition"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.objecttransition {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: -80%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.move {
  left: 10%;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
  $('#block').addClass('move');
});
```

Comment: this is not the mid... when i have a wide screen i will run into problems displaying some in center!

Comment: this will center the div since `left` was set to be `10%` and the div's `width` is `90%`, leaving another `10%` space to its right side, occupying the whole screen and centering the div.

Comment: oh, ok :) im not a friend off such dynamic windows. of course there should be dynamic but in this case the content of the centered div will be really freaky ^^

Answer (score 0):

first of all you might should use

[.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

or

[.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

but to center it via css you have to do some like

```
.foobar{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -50px 0 0 -50px; /* half of height | 0 | 0 | half of width */
}
```